# Creating a new folder each time Selenium WebDriver takes a screenshot

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```java
// Take screenshot method
static void captureScreenshot(String fileName) throws IOException {

// Take the screenshot and store as file format
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Open the current date and time
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy__hh_mm_ss").format(new Date());

//Copy the screenshot on the desire location with different name using current date and time
    Cache.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\Kiko Kikostov\\IdeaProjects\\AboutPagesBanerScreenSizes\\15inchScreenSize\\Asia\\" + fileName + " " + timestamp + ".png"));
    String st = scrFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String str = scrFile.getParent();
    scrFile = new File(str+"/"+ "/" + fileName);
}
```

This works fine for me but I want to implement that every time the test is run a new folder or subfolder is created inside the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory with the `os`

```
import os
  
directory = "MyFolder"
parent_dir = "D:/Pycharm projects/"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)      
os.mkdir(path)
print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)
```

So, for your usecase should be something like this:

```
import os
parent_dir="C:\\Users\\Kiko Kikostov\\IdeaProjects\\AboutPagesBanerScreenSizes\\15inchScreenSize\\Asia\\";

// Take screenshot method
static void captureScreenshot(String fileName) throws IOException {

// Take the screenshot and store as file format
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Open the current date and time
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy__hh_mm_ss").format(new Date());

// Assuming you want a folder with the timestamp
directory = timestamp;
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)      
os.mkdir(path)

//Copy the screenshot on the desire location with different name using current date and time
Cache.copyFile(scrFile, new File(directory + fileName + " " + timestamp + ".png"));
String st = scrFile.getAbsolutePath();
String str = scrFile.getParent();
scrFile = new File(str+"/"+ "/" + fileName);
```

Comment: you can also use mkdir on a File object... ex:   File file = new File("c:\path_to\folder\timestamp\");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
            } }